# Resizing SplitPane Programmatically

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to layout a Stage using a GridPane as the root of the Scene.

```
row 1 contains a HBox
row 2 contains a SplitPane with orientation set to Vertical
```

The SplitPane contains a browser control and another SplitPane with orientation set to Horizontal. The inner SplitPane contains two TableViews.

I'm try to have the outer SplitPane resize as the window changes size (please forgive if I'm not using the correct terms). I've seen how this can be done when using fxml but I'm restricted to using Javafx 8 and must do this programmatically. If it matters I'm using Netbeans 8.1.

It would be most appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

thank you
A.G.

Comment: It's pretty simple to "translate" fxml to java code...

Comment: @fabian - translating fxml to java code might not be difficult for many node properties. Still some properties such as the double maxWidth can be set to string values such as "-Infinity" in fxml. Under the hood some form of type converter is likely used to progressively set the property as the node's size changes.

Comment: `"-Infinity"` for target type `double` is `Double.valueOf("-Infinity") = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. It's almost always the `valueOf` method of the target type (or it's wrapper class) that is used. And no, this doesn't create any binding or anything else that updates the size beyond the usual layout.

Comment: @fabian - thank you for the clarification. Such information isn't readily available via Oracle's documentation. I consider that any "valueOf" method to be figuratively if not literally a type converter.  

thank you again my friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
 yourSplitPane.setMinSize(500, 400);
 yourSplitPane.setMaxSize(500, 400);
```

Here, 500 is width and 400 is height.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the solution to resizing the outer SplitPane was to use the type's static setResizableWithParent method.

```
SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(outerPane, Boolean.TRUE);
```

With that addition the SplitPane resized vertically but was limited horizontally by the width of the GridPane. The grid only contains one column so setting a ColumnConstraint's PercentWidth property to 100 allows the grid and SplitPane to resize horizontally.